# Transitioning between activities without moving actionbar

Tags: android-layout, android

Does anyone know how to transition between activities without animating the actionbar like in the Gmail app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a transition between `Activities`, but between `Fragments`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

`Fragments` were introduced in 3.0, but there is a backport library in the android SDK. You can use them from and above API level 4.

Comment: Okay, I see now that other aspects of the gmail app do not do that. Is there a way to mimic that behavior with activities though?

Comment: No, an activity is an entire UI component that consumes the entire screen space. The idea of fragments was just that - divide UI up into fragments. If you follow a good MVC pattern it should be a breeze to transition.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't actually answer the question.